# Curried JavaScript function for fluent API

Tags: javascript, fluent, currying

I want to write a default callback for HTTP-requests made with [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent). The calls are all made with the [async.parallel()](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) framework and the overall result handled together. The callback should handle the results from the HTTP-requests and return a default value, if an error occured. The default value can be specified, but `null` will be used if it was not set.

I want to construct my handler using a fluent syntax like this:

`handle(done).withDefaultValue([])` (empty array is set as default value)

`handle(done)` (null is used as default value)

I'm relatively new to function currying. Here's what I've tried:
I created a Node module which should be eventually used like this:

My code in `handle.js`

```
module.exports = function(done){
  this.withDefaultValue = function(defaultValue){
    return function(err, result){
      if(err){
        debug('handling error ' + err + ' and returning default value ' + defaultValue)
        return done(null, defaultValue)
      }
      // sanity check for null and empty objects
      result = _.isEmpty(result)?[]:result
      done(null, result)
    }
  }
  return this
}
```

My code in `somefile.js`

```
var handle = require('handle')
async.parallel([
   function(done){
     api.myApiCall(arg1, arg2, handle(done).withDefaultValue([]))
   },
   function(done){
     api.myOtherApiCall(arg1, arg2, handle(done))
   }
], function(err, result){
})
```

Above code works for the first call (the one with `withDefaultValue([])`, but not for the second call:

`Unhandled Error:  handle(...).withDefaultValue is not a function`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you say it works for the second call but not the first, you mean that the second function in `async.parallel` works, but not the one that uses `widthDefaultValue`?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this wrong. It works for the first call (the one with `withDefaultValue`) but not for the second call. I corrected this in the description above now.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with currying. Did you mean to use the term "method chaining"?

Comment: Yes, method changing would probably be the right term here, but I thought I could achieve this with currying here, because I'm partially executing a function in one case and curry it with a default value in the second...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```js
console.log = x => document.write(x + "<br>");



function handle(func) {

    var handler = function(param) {
        console.log('doing stuff...');
        func(param);
    };

    var ret = handler.bind(this, "default");

    ret.withDefault = function(val) {
        return handler.bind(this, val);
    }

    return ret;
}


function done(param) {
    console.log(param)
}

setTimeout(handle(done));
setTimeout(handle(done).withDefault(123));
```

Comment: this does not seem to be the same like I described (at least not exactly). If I get you right, your `handle(func)` maps to my `module.exports` with `param` being my `done`-function, the `handler` to the `function(err, result)` in my code. This seems to work, but only partly, because I can not access the err (which is set by superagent):

module.exports = function(done){

  var handler = function(err, result){
    return done(err, result)
  }

  var ret = handler.bind(this, null, {})

  ret.withDefaultValue = function(val){
    return handler.bind(this, null, val)
  }
  return ret
}